# How can I make my Erlang process run on selected interfaces?

Tags: erlang

I have an Erlang process which is started from a shell script. Currently it is started with option `inet_dist_use_interface` as `0.0.0.0`.

Now I have a requirement to run it only on specific interfaces. I see that `inet_dist_use_interface` takes only one interface.

How can I extend it to take multiple IP addresses?